# Summarising Multiple Columns in R (while retaining filter)

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I've hit a bit of a brick wall with my code below. Essentially, dftable should be a filtered dataframe containing clicks on a widget (I loop through the columns for each widget).

I then want to get the sum of all pageviews the widget was active on (it's not on all pages, and I filter as such to exclude those where it is NA). However, dfviews just returns all pageviews, as opposed to filtering on where the widget is not NA.

Any guidance would be appreciated:
mixpanelData example:

```
     --------------------------------------------------------------
     | Group | Date   | WidgetClick | Widget2Click | ViewedPageResult
     --------------------------------------------------------------
     | ABC  | 01/01/2017    | 123456      | NA          |  1450544
     --------------------------------------------------------------
     | ABN  | 01/01/2017    | NA          | 1245        |  4560000
     --------------------------------------------------------------
     | ABN  | 01/02/2017    | NA          | 1205        |  4561022
     --------------------------------------------------------------
     | BNN  | 01/02/2017    | 1044        | NA          |  4561021
     --------------------------------------------------------------
```

An my ideal output would be along the lines of... (with proportions, which is fine as I can handle these)

```
     WidgetClick CSV
     --------------------------------------------------------------
       Date       | WidgetClick | ViewedPageResult
     --------------------------------------------------------------
      01/01/2017    | 123455    |  1450544
     ------------------------------------------------------------
      01/02/2017    | 1044      |  4561021
     --------------------------------------------------------------

     WidgetClick 2 CSV
     --------------------------------------------------------------
     |Date       | Widget2Click | ViewedPageResult
     --------------------------------------------------------------
      01/01/2017    | 1245        |  4560000
     --------------------------------------------------------------
      01/02/2017    | 1205        |  4561022
     --------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code is provided below...

```
vars = colnames(mixpanelData)
vars =vars[-c(1,2)]
k = 1
for (v in vars) {
    filename <- paste(v,k,".csv",sep="")
    dftable <- mixpanelData %>% filter(!is.na(v)) %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise_(clicksum=interp(~sum(var, na.rm = TRUE), var = as.name(v)))

dfviews <- mixpanelData %>% filter(!is.na(v)) %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(viewsum=sum((ViewedPageResult)))
total <- merge(dftable,dfviews,by="Date")
total <- mutate(total, proportion = clicksum / viewsum * 100)
   write.csv(total, file = filename,row.names=FALSE, na="")
   k <- k +1 }
```

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible data example as well as your desired result?

Comment: Yes - I've added some sample tables. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your desired results, you show two separate tables. But you also mention that you have several widgets, so separate table might not be ideal. I'll show how you can get separate tables and then I'll show how you can calculate for all widgets at once.

**Separate tables**

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can use filter to get your two tables like so:

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)
df <- read.table(text="Group  Date    WidgetClick  Widget2Click  ViewedPageResult
ABC   01/01/2017     123456       NA            1450544
ABN   01/01/2017     NA           1245          4560000
ABN   01/02/2017     NA           1205          4561022
BNN   01/02/2017     1044         NA            4561021",header=TRUE,
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df%>% filter(!is.na(WidgetClick)) %>% select(-Widget2Click)
  Group       Date WidgetClick ViewedPageResult
1   ABC 01/01/2017      123456          1450544
2   BNN 01/02/2017        1044          4561021

df%>% filter(!is.na(Widget2Click)) %>% select(-WidgetClick)
  Group       Date Widget2Click ViewedPageResult
1   ABN 01/01/2017         1245          4560000
2   ABN 01/02/2017         1205          4561022
```

**Single table**

To get all the results in a single table, you first need to `gather` the Widget*Click column and then `filter`:

```
df%>%
  gather(Widget_number,Click,starts_with("Widget"))%>%
  filter(!is.na(Click)) 

  Group       Date ViewedPageResult Widget_number  Click
1   ABC 01/01/2017          1450544   WidgetClick 123456
2   BNN 01/02/2017          4561021   WidgetClick   1044
3   ABN 01/01/2017          4560000  Widget2Click   1245
4   ABN 01/02/2017          4561022  Widget2Click   1205
```

**EDIT**

To `summarise` the number of clicks per month per widget, you can `mutate` to add a `Year_mon` column using `as.yearmon` from package `zoo`. Then, `group_by` `Widget_number` and `Year_month`, then `summarise` to get the total clicks per month. You can do other calculations such as proportion inside the `summarise` statement. I assumed the date was "%m/%d/%Y". Make sure it's the case.

```
library(zoo)
df%>%
  gather(Widget_number,Click,starts_with("Widget"))%>%
  filter(!is.na(Click)) %>%
  mutate(Year_month=as.yearmon(as.Date(Date,"%m/%d/%Y"))) %>%
  group_by(Widget_number,Year_month) %>%
  summarise(Sum_clicks=sum(Click,na.rm=TRUE))

  Widget_number    Year_month Sum_clicks
          <chr> <S3: yearmon>      <int>
1  Widget2Click      Jan 2017       2450
2   WidgetClick      Jan 2017     124500
```

Comment: This is great - thank you. Is there anyway you drop the 'Group' so the second table provides a roll up of the monthly data, as opposed to by Group?

Comment: @Hemmed There is a way to aggregate data by month, but how exactly would you like that? A sum? A mean? Of which columns?

Comment: Sum would be amazing, that's what I'm trying to do with this here:
 dftable <- mixpanelData %>% filter(!is.na(v)) %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise_(clicksum=interp(~sum(var, na.rm = TRUE), var = as.name(v)))

Comment: Thank you. With this, am I still able to get the proportion of pageviews? For example, ViewedPageResult will have different values per widget, per month, as not all widgets are on all pages. Should I extend this `group_by(Widget_number,Year_month) %>%` to `group_by(Widget_number,ViewedPageResult,Year_month) %>%`

Comment: @Hemmed Your code seems logical. I didn't do that because I didn't have enough data points for ViewedPageResult and summarise would have done nothing. However, with your data, it should work.